# The algebra of polynomials on the closed unit circle is not self-adjoint

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials, solution-verification

**The question**

> Let $D = \{z \in \Bbb C: [|z| \leq 1]\}$ and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra of all the complex-valued polynomials on $D$. Prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is not self-adjoint.

**My attempt**

Let us consider the following polynomial in $\mathcal{A}$:
$$P(z) = z, \hspace{5mm} z \in D$$
then its conjugate is the function:
$$f(z) = \bar{z}, \hspace{5mm} z \in D$$
Now, suppose that there exists a polynomial $Q \in \mathcal{A}$ such that:
$$Q(z) = \bar{z}, \hspace{5mm} z \in D$$
then, since the RHS is zero if and only if $z = 0$, $Q$ is a polynomial with just one root, namely $0$. Therefore:
$$Q(z) = az, \hspace{5mm} z \in D, a \neq 0 $$
and if equate it with $\bar{z}$ and multiply both sides by $z$ we obtain:
$$az^2 = |z|^2$$
Finally, if $Im(a) \neq 0$ then letting $z=1$ yields a contradiction (the RHS is real), otherwise, if $Im(a) = 0$ then letting $z=i^{1/2}$ yields the same contradiction.

I would like to know if my answer is correct and satisfactory.

---

As always, any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: Looks fine. The last part can be argued in many ways. I would have been more lazy and just say that $Q(z)$ is analytic and $\overline{z}$ is not. Or computed $\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}$, which is zero for $Q$ and $1$ for $\overline{z}$.

Comment: @user85667 Thank you very much for your time and your other suggestions!